# (MySQL) user table and profile separate, or same table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

I'm creating a blogging site that anyone can sign up and be an author for. I want each author to have their own public profile. My main question is; would it be better practice to have a separate profile table that contains fields that would be specific to only the profile page, or should I just add those profile fields to a general users table as this example shows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
 `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
 `admin` int(1) 0 ,
 `bio` text NOT NULL,
 `profile_pic` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

bio and profile_pic are both profile fields in this case. This is also just an example, I plan to have more fields for general user stuff and not to many more for the public profile, but that could change as I move further into development.

Sorry if this an opinion and not a best practice question. I'm new to Database architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep them together.  You're describing [vertical partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)#Partitioning_methods), which is generally only used when a table is getting *really* wide - dozens or hundreds of fields.  Until and unless there's a compelling reason to separate them (e.g., a single blogger can have multiple profiles, for different blogs, audiences, or languages), there's no need to complicate the schema.

Comment: Another useful case for Vertical Partitioning is if some of the fields are _really_ bulky (TEXT/BLOB) and are not needed all the time.

Comment: Interesting, @RickJames. My understanding in MS SQL is that such columns are always stored out-of-row, so vertical partitioning isn't useful, but it seems that MySQL is [a little more complicated](http://mysqlserverteam.com/externally-stored-fields-in-innodb/).

Comment: There are several flavors (at least 4) row-format in InnoDB, so I guess "it depends".  And (if I recall correctly) you need 5.6.3 (or later), `innodb_file_format=Barracuda`, `innodb_file_per_table=ON`, and `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`;